# Can you "empower" a goal rather than a person?

Tags: word-usage

I want to write: "...to empower individual health."

However, I can't think of examples where "empower" takes a direct object that is not a person. You can empower a person, but can you empower a goal?

If not, what other verbs would get the message across while using this syntactic structure?

Answer (score 6):

I don't see how inanimate objects, abstract concepts, etc., could meaningfully be "empowered".
In OP's context a better choice of verb would be ["To **promote** individual health".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To%20whosoever%20it%20may%20concern%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22To%20promote%20individual%20health%22&tbm=bks)

> [**promote**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/promote) *- to help or encourage to exist or flourish; further*

Comment: I'm stylistically inclined to agree, but oddly (see my answer below) others have chosen fit to use it in this inanimate sense--at least according to the Google n-gram data.

Comment: @jbeldock, did you delete your answer?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks. I considered using "promote" but feel that "empower" has a useful connotation of individual engagement that "promote" doesn't.

Comment: Yes.   I didn't see any point to the continuing aggressive criticism.  This used to be a friendly place.  Such a shame....

Comment: @jbeldock: I'm sorry you feel the criticism was *aggressive*. Like Susan, I thought your answer was inherently incorrect, but it seemed to me our comments were intended to be *constructive*. Idiomatically, "health" is not something which can be "empowered", and it would be extremely unusual to speak of "life" being empowered (it certainly wouldn't in OP's context)...

Comment: ... The fact that you can *empower health **workers*** (or *professionals, organisations,* etc.) has no direct bearing on OP's question *(Can you empower an abstract concept?)*. My comments were intended to show *why* you were apparently able to justify your erroneous position using NGrams (by taking collocations out of context). I've been on ELU longer than you, and I can assure you I've been more robustly criticised than you for making the very same mistake. It still happens sometimes, but I try to take more care nowadays.

Comment: Both of you ignored the four textual examples I provided which did not rely on ngrams.  My answer explicitly stated it was an unusual use.  Yet you both focused only on the ngram data.  Since both if you are very high ranking members of ELU, it is clear that this is your territory and we must play by your rules, which evidently includes being abrupt to the point of rudeness and willfully ignoring other parts of an answer in order to criticize a portion you don't like.  I'm glad you have both found a forum for such "constructive" behavior.  I don't have to like it.

Comment: @jbeldock: Your style continues to be abrasive, so I'm not sure this interaction is likely to get us anywhere useful. Three of your four examples use *health* as an adjective modifying the substantive noun *(prevention, innovation, translation)*. Personally, I don't think *any* of those are very appropriate subjects for *empowerment*, but they're certainly a lot more credible than *health* as an abstract noun. I just don't think it's very helpful to advise someone who appears to be a non-native speaker that such usages are "acceptable" in any real sense.

Comment: OK, let's end this.  You have the high ranking, so you are the arbiter of appropriate behavior.  I gave up by deleting my post.  Yet you continued your criticisms here, and now you're calling me abrasive.  If your intent is to frighten away users with good intent but less stature than yours, you are succeeding.